# Getting unexpected alert when calling a function from another in the same JavaScript object

Tags: javascript

```
  var sn = {
                di: function (val) {
                    alert(val);
                }, mn: function () {
                    this.di("Hello");
                }
            };
  alert(sn.mn());
```

when i am executing this program i am getting two alerts, The first alert is the correct one and second one is not expected and gives 'undefined'
why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get two alerts

1. The first is the hello as shown by function di
2. The second alert that you get is undefined which is the return value of the function mn which returns nothing/undefined.

**A short exercise to debug it**

To see from where you get the undefined , put a return statement inside your mn function.

Answer (score 0):

in this code first sn.mn() will execute that will result the alert with Hello,

After that second alert will execute that will result the alert of return value of sn.mn function that is undefined.